# How to shuffle a str in place

Tags: rust

I want to shuffle a String in place in Rust, but I seem to miss something. The fix is probably trivial...

```
use std::rand::{Rng, thread_rng};

fn main() {
    // I want to shuffle this string...
    let mut value: String = "SomeValue".to_string();
    let mut bytes = value.as_bytes();
    let mut slice: &mut [u8] = bytes.as_mut_slice();

    thread_rng().shuffle(slice);

    println!("{}", value); 
}
```

The error I get is

```
<anon>:8:36: 8:41 error: cannot borrow immutable dereference of `&`-pointer `*bytes` as mutable
<anon>:8         let mut slice: &mut [u8] = bytes.as_mut_slice();
                                            ^~~~~
```

I read about String::as_mut_vec() but it's unsafe so I'd rather not use it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's no very good way to do this, partly due to the nature of the UTF-8 encoding of strings, and partly due to the inherent properties of Unicode and text.

There's at least three layers of things that could be shuffled in a UTF-8 string:

- the raw bytes
- the encoded codepoints
- the graphemes

Shuffling raw bytes is likely to give an invalid UTF-8 string as output unless the string is entirely ASCII. Non-ASCII characters are encoded as special sequences of multiple bytes, and shuffling these will almostly certainly not get them in the right order at the end. Hence shuffling bytes is often not good.

Shuffling codepoints (`char` in Rust) makes a little bit more sense, but there is still the concept of "special sequences", where so-called [combining characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character) can be layered on to a single letter adding diacritics etc (e.g. letters like `ä` can be written as `a` plus U+0308, the codepoint representing [the diaeresis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diaeresis_%28diacritic%29)). Hence shuffling characters won't give an invalid UTF-8 string, but it may break up these codepoint sequences and give nonsense output.

This brings me to graphemes: the sequences of codepoints that make up a single visible character (like `ä` is still a single grapheme when written as one or as two codepoints). This will give the most reliably sensible answer.

Then, once you've decided which you want to shuffle the shuffling strategy can be made:

- if the string is guaranteed to be purely ASCII, shuffling the bytes with `.shuffle` is sensible (with the ASCII assumption, this is equivalent to the others)
- otherwise, there's no standard way to operate in-place, one would get the elements as an iterator (`.chars()` for codepoints or `.graphemes(true)` for graphemes), place them into a vector with `.collect::<Vec<_>>()`, shuffle the vector, and then collect everything back into a new `String` with e.g. `.iter().map(|x| *x).collect::<String>()`.

The difficulty of handling codepoints and graphemes is because UTF-8 does not encode them as fixed width, so there's no way to take a random codepoint/grapheme out and insert it somewhere else, or otherwise swap two elements efficiently... Without just decoding everything into an external `Vec`.

Not being in-place is unfortunate, but strings are hard.

(If your strings are guaranteed to be ASCII, then using a type like the `Ascii` provided by [`ascii`](https://crates.io/crates/ascii) would be a good way to keep things straight, at the type-level.)

---

As an example of the difference of the three things, take a look at:

```
fn main() {
    let s = "U͍̤͕̜̲̼̜n̹͉̭͜ͅi̷̪c̠͍̖̻o̸̯̖de̮̻͍̤";
    println!("bytes: {}", s.bytes().count());
    println!("chars: {}", s.chars().count());
    println!("graphemes: {}", s.graphemes(true).count());
}
```

It prints:

```
bytes: 57
chars: 32
graphemes: 7
```

([Generate your own](http://eeemo.net/), it demonstrates putting multiple combining character on to a single letter.)

Answer (score 3):

Putting together the suggestion above:

```
use std::rand::{Rng, thread_rng};

fn str_shuffled(s: &str) -> String {
    let mut graphemes = s.graphemes(true).collect::<Vec<&str>>();
    let mut gslice = graphemes.as_mut_slice();
    let mut rng = thread_rng();
    rng.shuffle(gslice);
    gslice.iter().map(|x| *x).collect::<String>()
}


fn main() {
    println!("{}", str_shuffled("Hello, World!"));
    println!("{}", str_shuffled("selam dünya"));
    println!("{}", str_shuffled("你好世界"));
    println!("{}", str_shuffled("γειά σου κόσμος"));
    println!("{}", str_shuffled("Здравствулте мир"));

}
```

Comment: This worked like a charm. The only detail is that since you posted the answer rand has reorganized their code. shuffle is now part of the SliceRandom trait so you use: use rand::seq::SliceRandom; and to shuffle: gslice.shuffle(&mut rng);

Answer (score 0):

I am also a beginner with Rust, but what about:

```
fn main() {
    // I want to shuffle this string...
    let value = "SomeValue".to_string();
    let mut bytes = value.into_bytes();

    bytes[0] = bytes[1]; // Shuffle takes place.. sorry but std::rand::thread_rng is not available in the Rust installed on my current machine.

    match String::from_utf8(bytes) { // Should not copy the contents according to documentation.
        Ok(s) => println!("{}", s),
        _ => println!("Error occurred!")
    }
}
```

Also keep in mind that Rust default string encoding is UTF-8 when fiddling around with sequences of bytes. ;)

---

This was a great suggestion, lead me to the following solution, thanks!

```
use std::rand::{Rng, thread_rng};

fn main() {
    // I want to shuffle this string...
    let value: String = "SomeValue".to_string();
    let mut bytes = value.into_bytes();

    thread_rng().shuffle(&mut *bytes.as_mut_slice());

    match String::from_utf8(bytes) { // Should not copy the contents according to documentation.
        Ok(s) => println!("{}", s),
        _ => println!("Error occurred!")
    }
}
```

rustc 0.13.0-nightly (ad9e75938 2015-01-05 00:26:28 +0000)

Comment: This will shuffle the bytes of a string, but will randomly error since Rust strings are enforced to be UTF-8 and not every random shuffle of bytes is going to be UTF-8.

Comment: @reem, you're right. I accepted dbaupp's comment since it's a great explanation how to go about this in general.